# mysql dynamic sql

Tags: mysql, dynamic, null, execute, prepare

I have a question about the following code which I'm using in a prepare-execute stored procedure:

```
if(param_cod_empresa_pad='') then
set @param_cod_empresa_pad=true;
set @condicion18='and ? ';
elseif(param_cod_empresa_pad='0') then
set @param_cod_empresa_pad=null;
set @condicion18='and pc.cod_empresa_pad is ? ';
else
set @param_cod_empresa_pad=param_cod_empresa_pad;
set @condicion18='and pc.cod_empresa_pad=? ';
end if;
```

The second condition when param_cod_empresa_pad='0' doesn't work, I have to write it this way:

```
set @param_cod_empresa_pad=true;
set @condicion18='and pc.cod_empresa_pad is null and ? ';
```

Does anybody know why? I would like to know if there is a better way to call a null variable using dynamic sql in mysql.

I also tried:

```
set @param_cod_empresa_pad='null';
set @condicion18='and pc.cod_empresa_pad is ? ';
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `is` with parameters.
Alternatively you can use the `<=>` operator which is a `=` that returns true when comparing `null` values.

```
null = null   -> false
null <=> null -> true
1 <=> 1       -> true
1 <=> 2       -> false

elseif(param_cod_empresa_pad='0') then
set @param_cod_empresa_pad=null;
set @condicion18='and pc.cod_empresa_pad <=> ? ';
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's one of those hidden gems in MySQL.